# Use of strtok and strcpy in c++

Tags: c++

I'm using strcpy to copy a word from sentence into array of string. But this code is not working as expected. Please point out error if any..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i=0,j,k;
    char a[100],*str[100];
    char *b;
    cout<<"enter a sentence:\n";
    cin.getline(a,100);
    str[0] = strtok(a," ");
    while(str[i]!=NULL)
    {
        i=i+1;
        k=strlen(strtok(NULL," "));
        str[i]=new char[k+1];
        strcpy(str[i],strtok(NULL," "));
    }
    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]!=NULL)
        cout<<"\n"<<str[i];
        else
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First Rule: dont use "strcpy to copy"

Comment: There should be no reason whatsoever in C++ to use either of those functions.

Comment: @T.C.++ and also: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Just existence (and mentions in the reference) doesn't mean we should use it! There are things like _backwards compatibility_.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::string` instead of C-style strings?

Comment: And `std::istringstream` with `std::istream_iterator` for splitting.

Answer (score 1):

Two successive calls `strtok(NULL," ")` will not return twice the same pointer to a word in your string, as you seem to expect, but rather pointers to successive words. On the other hand you do seem to expect to get a pointer to a new token when you go around your `while` loop. That is not how things work.